# Editing Parquet Files as Binary

Tags: hive, parquet, amazon-athena, presto, orc

Assuming Parquet files on AWS S3 (used for querying by AWS Athena).

I need to anonymize a record with specific numeric field by changing the numeric value (changing one digit is enough).

1. Can I scan a parquet file as Binary and find a numeric value ? Or the compression will make it impossible to find such string ?
2. Assuming I can do #1 - can I anonymize the record by changing a digit on this number on the binary level without corrupting the parquet file ?

10X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not be possible. Parquet has two layers in its format that make this impossible: encoding and compression. They both reorder the data to fit into less space, the difference between them is CPU usage and universalness. Sometimes data can be compressed so that we need less than a byte per value if all values are the same / very similar. Changing a single value would than lead to more space usage which in turn makes your edit impossible.